# Trying to remove line and all following using sed but one line remains

Tags: sed

I'm removing this text from the bottom of some files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
```

(snipped for brevity) I'm using

```
sed -n -i '' '/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>/q;p' myfile.txt
```

The text is removed as expected but not the first line - I thought I was asking 'when you get to this line, remove it and everything following.'

(I seem to get everything removed when I just run this in a Terminal window, but not when saving the file.)

Mac user BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 'last if m{\Q<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\E}; ' in_file
```

For multiple files:

```
find /path/to/files ... -exec perl -i.bak -pe 'last if m{\Q<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\E}; ' {} \;
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

```
\Q          quote (disable) pattern metacharacters until \E
\E          end either case modification or quoted section, think vi
```

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: Thanks but now I need to know how to run this on a directory full of files. With sed, this works for me
`for file in *.emlx; do
    sed -n -i '' '/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>/q;p' "$file"
done`

Comment: Thanks @tim but I think I need to carry on with sed, your last clue gets me `zsh: permission denied:` Otherwise it works well.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution which removes all the lines I want to remove (in files in a directory).

```
for file in *.emlx; do
sed -i '' '/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>/,$d' "$file"
done
```